# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener not works if changed to other tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from background.js to content.js using the following code:

**Background.ts**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((_request, sender, _senderResponse) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, {method: 'test'});
};
```

**Content.ts**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
   message: `some msg`,
 }); 
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse) {
   if(message.method === 'test')
   console.log('Got message');
 });
};
```

The problem is: if I change or move to other tab or window, the contentScrip does not recive nothing in `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(...`

if tab is `active` works well.

when tab is `inactive` I get:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: sorry, I am using chrome.tabs.sendMessage with tab id. background and content is just a example that work well at the moment. the problem is if the tab is not focus does not receive the message. do you go it? @wOxxOm

Comment: ok. I did. @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, I want to send only to that tab's content script. for that reason I use  `sender.tab.id` if the tab is active works well. but I want that works also if the tab is inactive(not focus). when it is inactive I have this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: Without seeing the actual extension all I can say it sounds like a bug in Chrome or a bug in other code that you didn't show. The code present in the question can't behave like this but just in case, try moving chrome.runtime.onMessage before chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Comment: it did not work but thank you anyway